# getting the radio value and writing to back using innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html

I know that there has been a lot of questions regarding getting the radio button value and I have gone through them all. The issue I am having is that I have created a form and after it has been submitted I have to show the user again what radio button he chose using a modal. I created the modal and everything works fine. I am able to write the name and age of the user back into the new modal but the radio button is not selected. This is the javascript I have used

```
function displayContent(){
    var name=document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var comment=document.getElementById("comment").value;

    var ratings = document.getElementsByName('rating');
    var rate_value;     
    for(var i = 0; i < rating.length; i++){
    if(rating[i].checked){
       rate_value = rating[i].value;
    }

    return "";

   /*these lines are used to write the details into the new modal*/
   document.getElementById("username").textContent = name;
   document.getElementById("usercomment").textContent=comment;
   document.getElementById("userrating").innerHTML=rate_value;
}
```

Before i added the radio button array part the modal got the username and the comment but after that the entire thing didnt work. So i know that is where the issue is.Here is my Html

```
<form name="FeedbackForm">
    Name: <input id="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name"> 
    E-Mail: <input id="E-mail" type="email" placeholder="E-mail"> What do you think about us? <br>
    <textarea id="comment" rows="6" cols="33" "name="comment "></textarea><br>How would you rate us ?<br>
       <label><input type ="radio " name="rating " id="rating " value="Excellent ">Excellent</label>
       <label><input type ="radio " name="rating " id="rating " value="Very Good ">Very Good</label>
       <label><input type ="radio " name="rating " id="rating " value="Average ">Average</label>
       <label><input type ="radio " name="rating " id="rating " value="Poor ">Poor</label>
       <label><input type ="radio " name="rating "id="rating " value="Extreamly Poor ">Extremely Poor</label><br>
       <a href="# " id="submit " onclick="displayContent();setTimeout(closePopup,10000) ">SUBMIT</a>                                
</form>
```

Here is the Modal i created

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
        <p>Thank you
            <span id="username"></span> ,
            <br>Your feedback has been recorded.
            <br>
            <br>You commented that"
            <span id="usercomment"></span>"
            <br>
            <br>and rated our website "
            <span id="userrating"></span>".
            <br>
            <br>Thank you for taking your time to do so.
            <br>
            <br>You will now be re-directed automatically</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

please note that the quotation symbols i have used to put it around the "Comment the user enters"

Thank you in advance(Please note i want this done in java script as i have no idea about Jquery and i am not allowed to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in the code. But the biggest mistake seems to be the `return "";` right before the outputting of the input. The `return` works as a stop to a function and stopped it before it could output the answers. I think that this is what I think you wanted it to do:

```js
function displayContent() {
    var name=document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var comment=document.getElementById("comment").value;

    var ratings = document.getElementsByName('rating');
    var rate_value;        
    for(var i = 0; i < rating.length; i++){
        if(rating[i].checked){
            rate_value = rating[i].value;
        }
     }

     /*these lines are used to write the details into the new modal*/
     document.getElementById("username").textContent = name;
     document.getElementById("usercomment").textContent = comment;
     document.getElementById("userrating").innerHTML = rate_value;

     return "";
 }
```

```html
<form name="FeedbackForm">
    Name: <input id="Name"type="text" placeholder="Name">
    E-Mail: <input id="E-mail"type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    What do you think about us?<br>
    <textarea id="comment" rows="6" cols="33" name="comment"></textarea><br>
    How would you rate us ?<br>
    <label><input type ="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="Excellent">Excellent</label>
    <label><input type ="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="Very Good">Very Good</label>
    <label><input type ="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="Average">Average</label>
    <label><input type ="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="Poor">Poor</label>
    <label><input type ="radio" name="rating"id="rating" value="Extreamly Poor">Extremely Poor</label>
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="submit" onclick="displayContent()">SUBMIT</a>
    </form>

    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>

    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
            <p>Thank you <span id="username"></span>,
            <br>Your feedback has been recorded.<br> 
            <br>You commented that"<span id="usercomment"></span>" <br><br>and rated our website "<span id="userrating"></span>".
             <br><br>Thank you for taking your time to do so.<br><br>You will now be re-directed automatically</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much to you , i was actually unaware of how it affected. Thank you so much that small change made the difference

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with variable name.
use `rating` instead of `ratings`.

```
var rating = document.getElementsByName('rating');
```

This works for me.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work , thank you for taking your time to go through this